# Sending Basic HTTP POST when safe_mode ON and open_basedir is set

Tags: php, curl

I try to run basic cURL POST (below) where server config `safe_mode: ON` and `open_basedir option is set`. My hosting provider said this is for security purpose and my code must run in PHP version 5.2 below (their version is PHP 5.4). So far when I run the code it always returning array without any paramaters. Is there another way to effectively post data to a remote server like that. Thanks.

**simplepost.php** (in localhost)

```
<?php
//
// A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
//

$ch = curl_init();

// basic cURL option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://voulsa.qwords.org/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "number=12345&status=SUCCESS&msg=OK");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// receive return value from remote server
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($html);
?>
```

**test.php** (in remote site)

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: voulsa.qwords.org doesn't work for me - the DNS doesn't seem to be set up.

To find out what's going on enable verbose mode in cURL

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

Comment: @joep1978 do you mean enable verbose mode in **simplepost.php**? but no problem in here ^_^

Comment: Sorry the DNS works for me now.  I did mean in simplepost.php, but I've found the problem now - please see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your site is returning a HTTP 301 response, redirecting

```
http://voulsa.qwords.org/test.php
```

to

```
http://www.voulsa.qwords.org/test.php
```

The response is

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 26 Apr 2014 11:22:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.voulsa.qwords.org/test.php
Content-Length: 245
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Now this wouldn't be a problem if you could enable the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION setting which would follow the redirect but you can't, as due to the restrictions from your hosting company.

The easiest fix would be to query www.voulsa.qwords.org directly, eg change the URL in simplepost.php to be:-

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.voulsa.qwords.org/test.php");
```

The response from the new URL (having enabled CURLOPT_HEADER) is:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Apr 2014 10:56:54 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

Array
(
    [number] => 12345
    [status] => SUCCESS
    [msg] => OK
)
```

I haven't changed anything except the URL and enabling CURLOPT_HEADER and CURLOPT_VERBOSE but the code that works for me is:-

```
$ch = curl_init();

// basic cURL option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.voulsa.qwords.org/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "number=12345&status=SUCCESS&msg=OK");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// receive return value from remote server
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($html);
```

Comment: Sorry i'm not following. Change url into what? this is still the same url.

Comment: Sorry I typoed.  It needs to be www.voulsa.qwords.org, not voulsa.qwords.org

Comment: changing the url seems not changing anything. have you try it in you computer, does it return anything?

Comment: yes it works for me when I use www.voulsa.qwords.org - will add the logs above

Comment: you forget to add `www.` in the url ^_^. Many thanks it works now.